# Create object in 'with' statement without using a variable

Tags: variables, delphi, with-statement, declare

```
var 
  UserName, NickName, UserID: string;
begin
  with TStringList.Create do
  begin
    CommaText := 'ali,veli,4950';
    UserName := x[0];  //what is x ? (x is Tstringlist.create)
    NickName := x[1];
    UserID := x[2];
  end;   
end;
```

If I use the below code, it works. But I don't want to declare a variable. Can I use it with any variable?

In the `with` statement, how can I use it?

```
var 
  tsl: TStringList;
begin
  tsl := TStringlist.Create;
  with tsl do
  begin
    CommaText := 'ali,veli,4950';
    UserName := tsl[0]; 
    NickName := tsl[1];
    UserID := tsl[2];
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You don't need to refer to the list itself, you can access to items through their property, i.e: strings. Username := strings[0]; nickname := strings[1]; ....

Comment: Do yourself a favour, and stop using `with`. I have to maintain a code base where the original authors thought it was a good idea. It makes maintenance and debugging more difficult without saving significant time.
WHY don't you want to use a variable? Will it bite? What Delphi version are you targeting? If you are using 10.3 (Rio) or later you can use inline declarations:
 `var ts := TStringList.Create;
  try
    ts.CommaText := '...';
  finally
    ts.Free;
  end;`

Comment: You aren't going to get very far if your primary goal is to avoid using variables. You should not use with apart from a very rare set of highly specific scenarios. This isn't one of them.

Answer (score 7):

When an object is created directly in a `with` statement, there is no syntax to refer to that object (unless it provides a member that refers to itself, which is very rare), so you typically *must* use a variable, as your bottom code does.

Also, both codes are leaking the `TStringList` object, as you are not calling `Free()` on it when you are done using it.

That being said, in this *particular* example, the `[]` operator is just shorthand for accessing the `TStrings.Strings[]` default property, which you *can* access without needing a variable to the created `TStringList` object, just like you are doing with the `TStrings.CommaText` property, eg:

```pascal
var 
  UserName, NickName, UserID: string;
Begin
  with TStringList.Create do
  try
    CommaText := 'ali,veli,4950';
    UserName := Strings[0];
    NickName := Strings[1];
    UserID := Strings[2];
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: A real question would be, how to access the `.Strings[]` property within this block. I am getting compile time error. I am using `Strings`

Comment: @user30478 what is the actual error? What does your code look like?

Comment: No, theres no error with your answer. I had a slightly related question of accessing the (entire) `.Strings[] : TStrings` property of the SL within the with statement above. I found the related answer. It's not possible the way we want it. Should use an instance name. Maybe helpful for others in future so leaving in comment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791181/reference-object-instance-created-using-with-in-delphi