# Change TChart Size programmatically

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, teechart

I am creating a tChart programmatically (Delphi2007, TeeChar 7 free edition). I'd like  to set the chart dimension and maybe change the aspect ratio, but I don't get meaningful results changing Width and Height properties. I tried also changing the axis TickLength with no luck. I copied the relevant properties of TChart from a dfm file, not to forget anything meaningful. The aspect of the graph changes only when I edit X and Y max and min values, but this is not enough.

Here is my original chart and the "reformatted" one, as you can see the chart dimension is 400 x 250 for both. Is there a specific property for resizing charts? I want the axis to resize accordingly, is it possible? Thank you for your help

[image: First Chart]
[image: The same chart resized]

Here is the code relevant to TChart:

```
procedure CreateChart(parentform: TForm);
//actually formatChart is a CreateChart anf fChart a member of my class
begin
  fchart:= TChart.Create(parentform);
  fchart.Parent:= parentform;
  fchart.AxisVisible := true;
  fchart.AutoSize := false;
  fChart.color := clWhite;
  fchart.BottomAxis.Automatic := true;
  fchart.BottomAxis.AutomaticMaximum := true;
  fchart.BottomAxis.AutomaticMinimum := true;
  fchart.LeftAxis.Automatic := true;
  fchart.LeftAxis.AutomaticMaximum := true;
  fchart.LeftAxis.AutomaticMinimum := true;
  fchart.view3D  := false;
end

 procedure formatChart(width, height, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax: double);
 //actually formatChart is a method anf fChart a member of my class
 begin
   with fChart do  
     begin
       Color := clWhite;
       fChart.Legend.Visible := false;
       AxisVisible := true;
       AllowPanning := pmNone;
       color := clWhite;
       Title.Visible := False;
       BottomAxis.Minimum := 0; //to avoid the error maximum must be > than min
       BottomAxis.Maximum := xmax;
       BottomAxis.Minimum := xmin;
       BottomAxis.ExactDateTime := False ;
       BottomAxis.Grid.Visible := False ;
       BottomAxis.Increment := 5 ;
       BottomAxis.MinorTickCount := 0;
       BottomAxis.MinorTickLength := 5;
       BottomAxis.Ticks.Color := clBlack ;
       BottomAxis.TickOnLabelsOnly := False;
       DepthAxis.Visible := False;
       LeftAxis.Automatic := false;
       LeftAxis.AutomaticMaximum := false;
       LeftAxis.AutomaticMinimum := false;
       LeftAxis.Minimum := ymin;
       LeftAxis.Maximum := ymax;
       LeftAxis.Minimum := ymin;
       LeftAxis.TickLength := 5;
       Width := round(width);
       Height := round(height);
       View3D := False ;
     end;
 end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a name conflict here. You are using `with fChart`, and properties `Height` and `Width` of `fChart`. The same names are in your procedure call though, but the `fChart` width and height is used instead:

```
Width := Round(width); // The fChart property Width is used on both sides.
Height := Round(height); // The fChart property Height is used on both sides.
```

Rename the names in the procedure call, and it will work as it is supposed to.

Better still, avoid using the `with` keyword. See: [Is Delphi “with” keyword a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/514482/576719).

Comment: Thank you very much, the error was under my nose and I couldn't see it! I thought of being on the safe side using "with" just to save some typing in setting a long list of properties , but now the evilness of "with" has shown to me!

Comment: This has happened to many Delphi programmers I guess. A common practice  in procedure/function calls is to start every parameter name with an `A`. This could have saved you here, but as stated in the link, avoid the "with" keyword.

Comment: +1. I'd add a second upvote for the final sentence if I could. :-)

Comment: +1 Boy I wish someone would kill `with` as it causes failures on so many levels.

Comment: @Jeroen It's easy to kill it yourself by rejecting its use.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do; wish everyone would to that. And yes I know about the discussion.