# How can I chain method calls?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Consider this example:

```
 Memo1.Clear;
 Memo1.Add(S);
 Memo1.SaveToFile(F);
```

If it were in JavaScript, we could do that:

```
 Memo1.Clear.Add(S).SaveToFile(F);
```

How can I write my own Delphi classes to support chaining method calls like that? I'd like to be able to write code like this:

```
 MyFileClass.Create('File.txt').OpenForWrite().Add('Test');
```

Comment: No, there is no such built-in capability in Delphi. There are some libraries which do this however, such as OTL (Omni Thread Library). It's accomplished by making all functions in an object return its self. For example `function TMyObject.DoSomething(Param: String): TMyObject;`

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is known as 'duck typing'. There was a library to support this in Delphi around the time of XE2 release, but I don't believe it's been updated (and last time I tried it, it didn't work on XE3). I would be very interested in this as well, but unfortunately, as @JerryDodge says, it's not available in Delphi by default.

Comment: You should read some introductory text, really. Your JavaScript stylization makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @Scott Pritchard, no, ducks cannot type :-) See there: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Delphi_.28Object_Pascal.29

Comment: @user539484 Why a Russian article?

Comment: @Jerry Dodge, only for merit of Object Pascal example code, text is there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: A quick read of the documentation would have told you this isn't possible. `Memo1.Clear` is a procedure, so it has no return value, `Memo1` has no `Add` method (its `Lines` do, but it returns an integer that is the index into `Lines`). In order for your method chaining to work, each call would have to return an instance of `Memo1`, and all of the above clearly shows that they don't.

Comment: Just an Example: I want to create my Objects with this feature, not to use this on existent objects.

Comment: @EASI: then simply have every method return `Self`. Easy, but highly non-Delphi-ish. [Also, you mean 'classes', not 'objects'.]

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand you're right. It is more a java unorganized stuff, but is very cool!

Comment: Sadly we can't return values from a constructor...

Comment: *Sadly we can't return values from a constructor* Er, what do you mean? A constructor is a function that returns an instance of the class of which it is a member.

Comment: "is very cool" is a matter of opinion. It might be "very cool" while you write it now, but it's not "very cool" when you have to figure out what's not working six months from now and find out you have no reasonable place to set breakpoints to narrow the problem, or try to figure out what exactly you were trying to do when you wrote that code because you need to make a change.

Comment: Maybe, but I wont mess it up, I will keep it simple!

Comment: Guys, please do not downvote me. My questions are not so unimportant, I just do not elaborate the titles so well, and then, like now, takes time for you understand what I meant...

Comment: I haven't voted, but it is important to make sure your question is what you want it to be before going ahead and asking it.

Comment: In your example I'd include `IOUtils` and write `TFile.AppendAllText('file.txt','Test')`

Comment: Or I can do this: drawcircle.Paintit(black).moveto(1,1) and ir won't be a language disaster. Easy to read and to debug. I everybody is happy.

Comment: It can be useful, but it without garbage collection, this only works when you return `self` or value types (if you return a new object, you'll leak it), which is probably why this is not a very common pattern in Delphi.

Comment: Só we have to build our classes carefully

Comment: All programming should be done carefully :)

Comment: Yes, programming is cool. And it is also an opinion.

Comment: Two questions ago some users criticized me hardly because I asked an opinion and not an objective question. Now I asked a very object question. And they came with opinions about how undelphily is that code. I am beginning to ask myself if I should even be borned.

Comment: This question is not very objective too. I gave you two links, you can study them, close this broad discussion and then ask a practical question about implementing it while avoiding pitfalls it have (there are many).

Comment: @Wouter van Nifterick, it won't work well outside GC-enabled environments. It has been invented by Java guy, after all :-)

Comment: For those who things I am wrong to use that kind of method:
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/203469/if-my-team-has-low-skill-should-i-lower-the-skill-of-my-code

Comment: It's not because you *can* do it that you should, or that it would be an asset of the language. It's a horrible programming style, which quickly leads to unreadable code and which is debuggable. See also point 10 on [this page](http://www.pascal-central.com/top10.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can readily design your own classes to support a fluent style, should you so desire.

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  public
    function Foo: TMyClass;
    function Bar: TMyClass;
  end;

procedure TMyClass.Foo: TMyClass;
begin
  // do something
  Result := Self;
end;

var
  obj: TMyClass;

....
obj.Foo.Bar;
```

For many types, the fluent style is not appropriate, so don't feel you have to use it everywhere. However, for some types it can make good sense.

Comment: +1, but also want to note that using this style makes maintenance considerably more difficult and debugging a nightmare, so it should be used very sparingly.

Comment: @KenWhite I've personally never written such a class. However, I was using one the other way writing an expectation based NUnit test case to describe the exception that I wanted to see thrown by a piece of code. It's a style that sometimes has its merits.

Comment: I agree, as long as it's used extremely sparingly - in an NUnit test case, for instance ;-). Having worked on debugging code written by someone who thought this style was the way to do almost everything (and didn't last very long) and try to maintain it later, though, I'll even repeat *sparingly* a third time.

Comment: @Ken you make a good point about debugging. No fun to be had debugging a fluent statement with 10 dots!!

Comment: So it means javaScript debuggers have no life? ;-)

Comment: We could create a rule for this: do not step over 80 chars per line.

Comment: And do not chain unrelated methods.

Comment: @EASI: if you need many rules to govern something it may be better to do without that something in the first place...

Comment: Does this rule of your is valid for the State of for the Entire Society @MarjanVenema ;-) Just kidding...

Answer (score 3):

Can't speak for xe3, but my old Delphi5 could do it this way:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  public
    function Foo: Any;
    function Bar: Other;
    function Baz: Tipes;
  end;

var
  obj: TMyClass;

with obj do begin Foo; Bar; Baz; end;
```

or:

```
with obj do begin
  Foo;
  Bar;
  Baz;
end;
```

Not the same, but for more properties/methods quite useful.

Comment: Is it not the same as if you did not return the class? Come on! ;-)

Comment: I've read recently `with` may be on it's way out of the language. (It was related to this if I remember correctly: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/delphi_language_mobile_wp.html

Comment: First, the OP is probably already aware of the `with` construct; the question isn't about it. Second, why do you return `TMyClass` everywhere? This A is only confusing.

Comment: @Stijn: But I need `with TOpenDialog.Create(nil) do try ...`!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand with reference counting, you'll just need `var od:TOpenDialog; begin od:=TOpenDialog.Create(nil); if od.Execute then ... end;`

Comment: Second: I totally agree on this. Mea culpa. First: Can't agree: a) A classmate of mine asked me a very similar question and was very happy with this answer. b) Sometimes I just want to write clear code with existing classes and not my own. c) While the accepted answer is perfectly fine, some _other_ person might find this question looking for the second version, while people looking for the first will hardly be disturbed.

Comment: I find this answer creative. When you think of it, this does basically the same as what the op asks for, but here you can add breakpoints. +1 for thinking outside of the box.

Comment: Returning `Self` is the appropriate way to go to accomplish this (as I mentioned in my comment on the question). On a side note, the worst programming habit I've ever seen was `with Self do...`

Comment: No, I do not asked for the WITH clause. You can't chain the methods with it, just simplify by not add the object name twice. :-/

Comment: @EASI You made this pretty clear by accepting the other answer. (= My arguments above still stand nonetheless.

Comment: But your answer is a good example too, of a good ways of programming.

Comment: @EASI: if you think this a good way of programming, perhaps you are not aware of the dangers of the `with` statement and should read [Is Delphi “with” keyword a bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514482/is-delphi-with-keyword-a-bad-practice).

Comment: Well, I do not use it, just because almost all Delphi's classes have the same methods, we always have to specify at least one object that is not the one bind to `with` because it too have a method with the same name. It's good only with a few lines of code.