# Access the object of the using statement

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a using() without specifying object name.
My question is how can i access my new object and print its name ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AnimalFactory factory = new AnimalFactory();
        using (factory.CreateAnimal())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Animal {} created inside a using statement !");
            //How can i print the name of my animal ?? something like this.Name  ?
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Is the animal still alive ?");

    }
}

public class AnimalFactory
{ 
    public IAnimal CreateAnimal()
    {
        return new Animal();
    }
}

public class Animal : IAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Animal()
    {
        Name = "George";
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose invoked on Animal {0} !", Name);
        Name = null;
    }
}
public interface IAnimal : IDisposable
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Comment: just for curiosity , what you want to achieve and why the suggested or normal style does not appeal you

Answer (score 6):

Why do you want to do that? If you want access to the object here you should get a reference to it. (Assuming your example is representative of the problem you're trying to solve).

```
using (Animal a = factory.CreateAnimal())
{
   Console.WriteLine("Animal {0} created inside a using statement !", a.Name); 
}
```

Comment: I would like to avoid it, to make my code as simple as it can be without declare the object..

Comment: @ilansch: but you already have created an object. What do you try to avoid?

Comment: I am looking for a way to do this, but without create var = .. and then without writing var.Name inside the output. im not saying its possible, just trying to make a way to do it shortest.

Comment: What is the point of "shortest", @ilansch? It won't make your code any faster, and it certainly doesn't make it any clearer to manipulate an object to which there are otherwise no references in the code.

Comment: Declaring a variable introduces complexity?

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Declare variable:

```
using (var animal = factory.CreateAnimal())
{
}
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir: didn't know that, could you post a link with a sample?

Comment: p.s. shouldn't  `CreateAnimal` return `IAnimal` ? I think that's the basic of the Factory pattern...?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: you're right. I think, this should be a comment to question.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct. However, I'd like to throw a bit of the [language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029) in here (instead of saying "you can't")

Page 259:

> A using statement of the form
>
> > ```
> > using (expression) statement
> > ```
>
> has the same three possible expansions. In this case ResourceType is implicitly the compile-time type of the expression, if it has one. Otherwise the interface IDisposable itself is used as the ResourceType. **The resource variable is inaccessible in, and invisible to, the embedded statement.**

So, what you want to do is explicitly forbidden by the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want to accomplish is like Object Pascal Delphi

```
with MyClass.Create() do
try
   // Access method an properties of MyClass in here
finally
    free;
end;
```

I haven't found that in any other language, in C# you need to declare the variable:

```
(using MyClass a = new MyClass())
{
    a.properities/methods;
}
```

The only extra code that you don't need to code is the finally free.

Comment: Yes, Delphi allows this. And it is often considered bad practice because it allows for subtle scope changes when upgrading Delphi versions. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514482/is-delphi-with-keyword-a-bad-practice)