# Unobvious Delphi syntax error

Tags: delphi, text-files

I have a problem with some simple code I simply cannot resolve.  I'm using Delphi 5 with all updates applied.

I have this code block:

```
procedure TForm1.LoadBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   s1, s2, s3 : Textfile;
   sa, sb, RString, SQLString : string;
begin
  with sourcequery do begin
     Close;
     SQL.Clear;
     SQL.Add('delete * from source');
     ExecSQL;
     Close;
     AssignFile(S2, 'c:\delphi programs\events\source1.txt');
     AssignFile(S1, 'c:\delphi programs\events\source2.txt');
     Reset(s2);
     Reset(s1);
     while not eof(s1) do begin
        readln(s1, RString);
        SQLString := 'insert into source1(f1, f2) values(';
        SQLstring := SQLString+ QuotedStr(copy(Rstring, 1, pos(chr(9), Rstring)-1))+', ';
        SQLString := SQLString+QuotedStr(copy(Rstring, pos(chr(9),Rstring)+1,length(Rstring)))+')';
        with sourcequery do begin
           close;
           SQL.Clear;
           SQL.Add(SQLString);
           ExecSQL;
        end;
     end;
  end;
end;
```

When I try to compile it, though, it halts after "eof(" on this line:

```
 while not eof(s1) do begin
```

with the "missing operator or semi-colon" error message.

Try as I might I can find no error - missing operators OR semi-colons.  I have commented the file-reading block out and it compiles fine.  I've retyped it a number of times in case there were hidden special characters.  So far this is the entire program apart from the header information.

Can anyone spot the silly error?

Comment: You probably have a scope resolution issue. Try `while not System.eof(s1)...` instead.

Comment: and this is why you shouldn't use `with`

Comment: Thanks 500, that did the trick.  I have also tidied up the initial block where I delete the contents so that it is not the master block for the whole procedure.   How do I give you the big tick?

Comment: David A, why shouldn't I use "with"?   It's a fairly basic structure in Delphi.

Comment: And I don't think there should be an asterisk in your delete Sql (but maybe you're using an unusual Sql back-end).

Comment: You should not use with because it pollutes your namespace

Comment: "with" is evil, as it makes code hard to read. The IDE can't figure out what you mean, the next developer to look at the code will also be at a disadvantage.

Comment: MartynA - it used to be standard, but it's not any more.  However, most database systems probably just ignore it.   It works ...

Comment: @Christhornton That's interesting.  I would have thought it made the code easier to read.  Is there a discussion I can read of the why's and wherefore's anywhere?

Comment: "With Considered Harmful" -- http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2004/08/with-statement-considered-harmful.html

Comment: A nested with?!?  It burns!  IT BURNS!  Make it stop!

Comment: Reasons for not using `with`, [Is Delphi “with” keyword a bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514482/is-delphi-with-keyword-a-bad-practice).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All your code is wrapped in a `with sourcequery do begin` block, so any identifier within that block is first checked for whether it could be a member of `sourcequery`. That variable, evidently, has a member named `eof` that isn't a function. The compiler binds the `eof` name to that non-function instead of the function you expected it to be bound to, and therefore complains when you attempt to use it like a function.

The best solution is to stop using `with`. It leads to problems like this, where the apparent scope of names doesn't match the one the compiler sees. It also leads to problems debugging (because of a long-standing bug in the debugger, where it interprets names the way you did here, rather than the way the compiler interprets them). It can lead to other bugs, too. If you don't like typing `sourcequery.xyz` all the time, then you can create an alias for `sourcequery` that doesn't take up so much room:

```
var
  sq: TypeOfSourceQuery;
begin
  sq := sourcequery;
  sq.Close;
  sq.SQL.Clear;
  ...
```

If you really don't want to use that solution, then you can use the quick-and-easy solution, which is to qualify the `eof` name with the unit it belongs to. In your case, you want the function defined in the *System* unit, so change your code to indicate that:

```
while not System.Eof(s1) do begin
```

Comment: Rob, thanks for that.   I was going to remove the with block at the top of the program because it wasn't necessary anyway although I had planned to use it.   I don't mind not using the with blocks if there is a technical reason not to do so, although they are very handy.