# FireDac connection issue

Tags: delphi, firedac

I was using an example from here :

[establishing connection](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Establishing_Connection_%28FireDAC%29#Using_the_Login_Dialog)

Did it this way :

```
procedure TDataModule2.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
with FDGUIxLoginDialog1.VisibleItems do begin
  Clear;
  Add('Server=Strežnik');
  Add('User_name=Uporabnik');
  Add('Password=Geslo');
  Add('Database=Baza');
end;
try
FDConnection1.Connected := True;
except
  on E: EAbort do
  application.terminate;   // user pressed Cancel button in Login dialog

  on E:EFDDBEngineException do
    case E.Kind of
    ekUserPwdInvalid: ; // user name or password are incorrect
    //ekUserPwdExpired: ; // user password is expired
    ekServerGone: ;     // DBMS is not accessible due to some reason
    else
                 // other issues
    end;
end;
end;
```

However, application will not terminate after hitting cancel in the login dialog but shows my main form. What should I do to correct this ?

Also, how can I flash a message if the password was wrong, in this scenario ?

Firedac is connecting to SQL Server.

ps

Even this will not work :

```
.....
except
  on E: EFDDBEngineException do
  if E.Kind = ekUserPwdInvalid then
      begin
        ShowMessage('A user name or a password are invalid');
        Abort;
      end;
```

Comment: Have you added the relevant units/components to the datamodule? (the SQLServer driver and wait cursor?)

Comment: This will only work when hitting the cancel button on the dialog generates an exception. You should debug this to check that. Even if it does, what if the exception is not EAbort or EFDDBEngineException but some other exception, in that case nothing will happen here

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen here.  The `EAbort` exception you are looking for will only be caught at that moment ***if*** the exception is thrown at the exact instant that the database component is initially attempting to make connection.  If you want the application to terminate when they hit the cancel button then you have to implement that separately.  Further down, throwing an `EAbort` will not cause the application to terminate in and of itself - you have to catch this somewhere and do something with it (if it was a sensible way to halt the application, which it probably isn't)

Comment: Use "on E: EFDException do if E.FDCode = er_FD_ClntDbLoginAborted then Application.Terminate" instead of "on E: EAbort ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application usually quits by closing its main form.
You should never let an application quit by issuing an exception; it's bad form.

`EAbort` is not an exception that gets issued by the login dialog. In fact under normal circumstances te login dialog will not issue any exception.
If the user presses <kbd>Cancel</kbd> then the connection will not get ehm.. connected, you can test that.
[Here's a list of all the errors TFDConnection can generate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error).

The following code should work:

```
type
  TAction = (aSuccess, aGiveup, aWrongPassword, aPasswordExpired);

procedure TDataModule2.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  VI: TStrings; 
  WhatToDo: TAction;
begin
  WhatToDo:= aSuccess;
  VI:= FDGUIxLoginDialog1.VisibleItems; 
  VI.Clear;
  VI.Add('Server=Strežnik');
  VI.Add('User_name=Uporabnik');
  VI.Add('Password=Geslo');
  VI.Add('Database=Baza');
  try
    FDConnection1.Connected := True;
  except
    on E:EFDDBEngineException do case E.Kind of
      ekUserPwdInvalid: WhatToDo:= aWrongPassword;
      ekUserPwdExpired: WhatToDo:= aPasswordExpired;
      else WhatToDo:= aGiveUp;
    end; {case}
  end;
  if Not(FDConnection1.Connected) then WhatToDo:= aGiveUp;
  case Action of
    aWrongPassword: begin
      ShowMessage('You've entered a wrong username or password please try again');
      DataModuleCreate(Sender);
      Action:= aSuccess;
    end;
    aPasswordExpired: ShowMessage('You password has expired, please request a new one from the PHB');
  end;
  if Action <> aSuccess then Application.Terminate;
end;
```

**Comments about coding style**
Do not use `with`. [With](https://stackoverflow.com/a/515933/650492) is evil use a temporary variable instead and use that to reference the nested variable(s).

Terminating on an error without issuing an error is really silly.
No user is going to be happy having an application die on them without any explanation why.

You should never terminate on a wrong password or username.
As least give the user the change to try again 3 or 4 times.
If he doesn't get it right by then issue the "wrong username or password" error message and quit.
Never tell the user which (username or password) is wrong, an attacker can use that to generate a list of usernames.