# How to extract all email address from an Indy TIdMessage object?

Tags: delphi, indy10

Using Indy, how can I extract all email addresses that are present in the `To`, `Cc` and `Bcc` fields of a `TIdMessage`?  As these fields can contain more than one address, I must parse them, but I didn't find any ready-made function for that (maybe I've missed it?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You obviously did not read the

[`TIdMessage` documentation:](http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/007544.html)

> [`TIdMessage.BccList`](http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/012414.html)
>
> [`TIdMessage.CCList`](http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/012414.html)
>
> **`TIdMessage.Recipients`**
>   Identifies the recipients of a message.
>
> `property Recipients: TIdEmailAddressList;`
>
> **Description**
>   Recipients is a `TIdEMailAddressList` property used to store `TIdEmailAddressItem` values that identify the recipients of the message. Use `CCList` for recipients to receive a Carbon Copy of the message. Use `BCCList` for recipients to receive a Blind Carbon Copy of the message.

All of these properties give you a [`TIdEmailAddressList`](http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/007308.html) that you can harvest for addresses.

This is the second item in a google search for [`Indy TIdMessage`](https://www.google.nl/search?q=indy%20tidmessage).

For example:

```
function GetEmailAddresses(const Email: TIdMessage): TStringList;
var
  Item: TIdEmailAddressItem;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  for Item in Email.Recipients do Result.Add(Item.Address);
  for Item in Email.CcList do Result.Add(Item.Address);
  for Item in Email.BccList do Result.Add(Item.Address);
end;
```

Note that the Indy documentation uses the `with` keyword a lot.
Although convenient, [using `with` is a very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514482/is-delphi-with-keyword-a-bad-practice) and I recommend you avoid it at all costs.

Comment: thanks johan i miss it :( but i do not use anymore google because of privacy problem with google ;) and i use maybe wrong keyword on stackoverflow ! anyway thanks a lot