# set the background color of a themed StatusBar component

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

How can I set the background color of a themed [`TStatusBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TStatusBar) component?  When I set the color property, it only works if the `Enabled runtime themes` is disabled.

thanks in advance.

Comment: A purpose of themes: to ensure a consistent color and font scheme. So it really is to be expected that when themes are enabled, most if not all changes to color and font properties are ignored.

Comment: i want to change the color because is for display alert messages for the user and gain their attention.

Comment: Themes are to allow the user to control the colors. You should work with them, not try to fight against them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you require, but you could simply disable the Theme Painting for a specific control, in this case your Statusbar, like so:

```
Uses
  uxTheme;

SetWindowTheme(StatusBar1.Handle, '', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own OwnerDraw-Event and draw the StatusBar (to be precise: every Panel on it!) with your own colors:

```
procedure TForm1.StatusBar1DrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar;
  Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect);
begin
  with StatusBar.Canvas do begin
    Brush.Color := clRed;
    FillRect(Rect);
    TextOut(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, 'Panel '+IntToStr(Panel.Index));
  end;
end;
```

But with themes on it is not possible to change the color in the Object-Inspector.

Comment: Just a few hints: 1) There is no need to specify statusbar1 in your code, because event already passes TStatusBar. 2) For this to work, you need to set panel's style to psOwnerDraw. 3) I am not a big fan of with constuct.

Comment: 1) OK. Edited. 2) Yes. 3) It is mostly a matter of taste, isn't it?

Comment: `with` is considered harmful, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71419/whats-wrong-with-delphis-with