# What's the "with ... do" swift equivalent

Tags: swift, delphi, swift2

When coding in Delphi, I can use this syntax to make my code better seen:

```
with person do begin       
    setFirstName("Frodo");
    setLastName("Baggins");
    setAge(25);
    enableRing;
    sendToQuest;
end;
```

That would be the same of:

```
person.setFirstName("Frodo");
person.setLastName("Baggins");
person.setAge(25);
person.enableRing;
person.sendToQuest;
```

That's only for code better looking, nothing else.

Is there any equivalent of Delphi's "with .. do" syntax in swift 2?

Comment: Really, the "let ..." idiom is the closest. basically the answer is "no"

Comment: No, and the best advice anyone can give related to Delphi and `with` is *stop using it*. It leads to tons of problems and bugs, and produces difficult to read, maintain, and debug code. Rather than looking for an equivalent in Swift, you should be working to eliminate it in Delphi.  (And rumor has it that it is soon to be deprecated and may not be supoorted in future Delphi versions.)

Comment: @KenWhite well, i disagree with you, principally on the "difficult to read" part. I use it for a long time and had never been leaded to a bug. Your comment is based in something more than rumors? Is there any material stuff that i can read about it? thank's anyway

Comment: My comment about future deprecation is based on what people at Embarcadero (particularly Marco Cantu, IIRC) have said publicly in blog posts and on the EMBT forums. My *difficult* comment is based on nearly two decades of Delphi experience, trying to debug crappy code others have written using `with`. A local variable and single line assignment makes the code much cleaner: `var p: TPerson; begin p := Person; p.setFirstName('Frodo'); p.setLastName('Beggins');`, and you don't end up with bugs caused by scope.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71419/why-should-i-not-use-with-in-delphi

Comment: It's also based on hundreds of posts from others (some here on SO) about bugs that have been caused by use of `with`.

Comment: @graymatter: Thanks. You found that link faster than I could.

Comment: @KenWhite I figured there had to be something. I have yet to see a single instance that justifies the use of the with statement. At best you are left with code that will be more difficult for someone else to read and work with.

Comment: @KenWhite thank's again. Well, there's no material stuff about it being deprecated, right? Even at the link posted, i don't think the problem was the "with ... do" statement, but the way it was used. Like you said, "crappy code". We're talking about personal opinion here. My opinion is that this statement can be dangerous (like a lot of otters), but it makes the code very better looking.

Comment: As I said, read Marco's blog (http://www.marcocantu.com). He's the Product Manager for RAD Studio (which includes Delphi) and has made the statement about future deprecation. "Crappy code" can mean "good code that ends up being crappy because use of `with` causes unintentional scoping issues that bite you in the backside". And you're absolutely right. It's personal opinion - just offering constructive advice based on years of experience. If you don't want it, suit yourself. You can tell yourself later *I should have listened to that guy.*. :-)

Comment: It's not that subjective.  What does this code do?
`with A, B do begin       x := y;     z := q; end`   Does it assign A.x the value of B.y, or the reverse, or does it do something that has nothing to do with A or B (also possible)? There are objective reasons WHY with is bad.

Comment: @KenWhite there's nothing on his blog saying that'll deprecated, but what do you think about: `with frm: TMyForm.Create(nil) do
try
frm.ShowModal;
finally
frm.Free;
end;` for example? That's pretty simmilar your p: TPerson example

Comment: @WarrenP this is an exactly example of crappy code... you should not use it that way. Look my previous comment ... what do you think about this usage?

Comment: i'm not a _with_ lover, i'm just adding content to this question, ok? That probably'll help someone ho has this _with_ doubt in future, maybe.

Comment: Your single line `with TMyForm.Create(nil) do try ShowModal; finally Free end;` code is fine, until you add more than `ShowModal`. There was an example of `with` hiding a problem posted yesterday (deleted now) by a new user. They wrote `var Obj: TObject; begin Obj := TLabel.Create(nil); with Obj do Caption := 'Something'; ... end;`, and were confused that the label didn't show. If `with` had not been used (`Obj.Caption := '';`,  the compiler would have told them that `TObject` doesn't have a `Caption`, but because of the `with` the compiler used the properties in scope (the forms). `with` bug.

Comment: As far as Marco's blog, he's got several years worth of posts. You looked for 10 minutes and decided there's nothing there? Look harder. Graymatter already posted one good link (with lots of discussion) about why `with` is a bad idea.

Comment: @Ken - Debugging crappy code is always a headache.  What specifically makes it crappy is less relevant than the fact that it is crappy in the first place.  You can dictate that people using `with` in a crappy way should stop using it completely (although this to me is just laziness given that you have the option of rejecting only crappy usage, but this would require *proper* code reviews as opposed to mere box-ticking on a checklist).  But the crappy developers will have other ways to write crappy code.  I suggest you eliminate the crappy developers and go from there.  ;)

Comment: @Deltics: I'm starting with telling all developers that work for me to stop using `with`, which eliminates a lot of the crappy code and turns some crappy developers into better developers overnight, and then I go from there. :-)

Comment: @Ken - I do not for one minute believe that you actually believe that.  You do not turn a bad cook into a good cook simply by requiring them to use a higher quality of ingredients.  All you do is make their bad cooking taste a little less bad than it did before.

Comment: @Deltics You will always have developers of varying abilities at a company. You can't just replace the ordinary ones with good ones as there are cost implications. Allowing with statements complicates code reviews. For better developers, even "good" use of with statements can turn bad. Later changes to an outside object could cause scoping issues. Take the case above where we have `with TMyObject.Create do aaa...` we could have problems down the line. Someone could delete `aaa` and the code would still compile if the owning object had `aaa`. I used inverted commas because there is no good use.

Comment: @Deltics I doubt anyone believes that banning `with` turns bad programmers into good programmers. But even the best programmers produce more dangerous and risky code if they start using `with`. The problem with `with` is that changes in one part of the code can have profound impact in other parts of the code. Even the best programmer cannot keep the entire program in memory at one instant.

Comment: dont use the with ... do syntax. Not only does it makes your code less readable but its a nightmare for debugging.

Comment: @Deltics: I didn't say *good developers* overnight. I said *better*, and eliminating `with` makes their code decidedly *better* than code littered with `with` (pun intended).

Comment: @KenWhite at his blog he has an search option that I used, that's why i told you that he didn't said about deprecation of _with_ in there. Maybe somewhere else.

Comment: @KenWhite anyway, it's now obvious that using this statement is harmful because it doesn't bring you any benefits except the "reading better"code depending of the situation and the right usage. So, I agree with you that's a bad idea. Thank's for your contribution on this question.

Answer (score 2):

I did manage to simulate this effect with a simple function...

```
func with<T>(_ element: T, _ make: (T) -> ()) {
     make(element)
}
```

*In case you do not like < make > you can replace it with < `do` > works same...*

and from:

```
 minLat = Swift.max(location.coordinate.latitude, minLat)
 minLong = Swift.max(location.coordinate.longitude, minLong)
 maxLat = Swift.min(location.coordinate.latitude, maxLat)
 maxLong = Swift.min(location.coordinate.longitude, maxLong)
```

I got:

```
with(location.coordinate) { c in
    minLat = Swift.max(c.latitude, minLat)
    minLong = Swift.max(c.longitude, minLong)
    maxLat = Swift.min(c.latitude, maxLat)
    maxLong = Swift.min(c.longitude, maxLong)
}
```

It came out pretty cute...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any equivalent of Delphi's "with .. do" syntax in Swift 2?

No there is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tuple type to set multiple fields of a struct.  This has much better encapsulation than the `with ... do` construct, although it looks like what you are trying to do would be better handled with an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use keyPaths. Although it doesn't really improve readability, it does shorten nested properties.

```
struct ExampleStruct {
    var somePropertyOfTheExampleStruct : CGPoint
}

var aVar = ExampleStruct(somePropertyOfTheExampleStruct: .zero)

// Change some values
aVar.somePropertyOfTheExampleStruct.x = 2.0
aVar.somePropertyOfTheExampleStruct.y = 3.0

// This does the same thing
let k = \ExampleStruct.somePropertyOfTheExampleStruct
aVar[keyPath: k].x = 2.0
aVar[keyPath: k].y = 3.0
```