# How to get the object reference inside a with block?

Tags: delphi, with-statement

In a `with` block I need to pass the object which is used with the `with` statement as function parameter.

```
with TMyObject.Create do
begin
  //...
  MyFunction( (* here I have to pass the created object *) );
  //...
end;
```

The same goal could obviously be achieved as follows:

```
var
  MyObj : TMyObject;
begin
  MyObj := TMyObject.Create;
  //...
  with(MyObj) do
  begin
     //...
     MyFunction(MyObj);
  end;
  //...
end;
```

...but I would know if there's a way to simplify my code and get the reference, without declaring the MyObj variable.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to refer to the "current with object".

Comment: I think you should not use "with" here at all and it will be best solution. Some linke here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71419/why-should-i-not-use-with-in-delphi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514482/is-delphi-with-keyword-a-bad-practice

Comment: It's a sign from God .......

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn: I fully agree with you and I never use `with` in my projects, unfortunately in this case I have to tell to another programmer how to change its code and I wanted to avoid to make him change hundreds of lines in which he's using the `with` statement. Anyhow, it seems it's the only way... Probably its better this way!

Comment: I have never understood the obsession to use `with...` that some people exhibit. But to still use it when you anyway have to declare a local variable for other reasons ... wow!

Comment: @TomBrunberg: Please read my previous comment

Comment: Yes, I read it when it popped up right after I posted my (interrupted by a phone call) comment. Your comment explains but doesn't justify leaving the hundreds of lines unchanged. Of course, this is only my opinion, and I'm not to say what your fellow programmer is to do.