# Storing Files in SQL Server Table (varbinary(max) column) using ADOQuery Component

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I'm using SQL Server 2019 and Delphi 10.3.

I need to store any kind of files ( like pdf, txt, docx, etc) in a 'Personal_Files' table.

This table is composed by a column with the file extension ( as varchar) and a varbinary(max) column to store the file itself.

I did some research on how to store these files on a table, but without success. Below some example:

```
var
Input,Output: TStream;
FName:        TFileName;

begin
...
     //Create Streams and encode Base64:
     Input  := TFileStream.Create(FName,fmOpenRead);
     Output := TFileStream.Create(FName+'Temp',fmCreate);

     TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(Input,Output);

... // Some validations

   // In the ADOQuery component, I did this:
  with ADOQuery, sql do
  begin
    close;
    clear;
    add('INSERT INTO MyDatabase.dbo.MyFilesTable (EXTENSION,FILEBIN)');
    add('VALUES (:wextension, :wfilebin)');
    Parameters.ParamByName('wextension').Value := TPath.GetExtension(FName);
    Parameters.ParamByName('wfilebin').Value   := Output.toString; 
    ExecSQL;
  end;
```

In this example, I tried to parse the stream as String, after the encode, but when I look in the SQL Table, it's the same stream for all the archives I tried. The parameter doesn't accept TStream type. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend not doing that and storing files in the *file* system, and storing the path only in the database.

Comment: Agree with Stu: keep them in the file system, Azure blob storage or S3 storage. Storing them in the database adds to your database storage costs, increase database backup costs (backups will take longer to perform and require more storage) as well as increase your RTO for no real benefit.

Comment: Aside: if you must store files in the database... it's a `varbinary` column, so why are you base64 encoding it and paying a 33% size penalty? i.e.: base64 takes 3 bytes of data and converts it to 4 US-ASCII characters.

Comment: Ouch, Thank You for the answers. I'll take your advice! So, by first, storing files directly on a table isn't good? And, the NetEncoding doesn't solve the size penalty?

Comment: [Why "with" is bad by Marco Cantu](https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2022-november-with-local-variables.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, and some advices, I found a way to send the file to my SQL Server table with ADOQuery. Altough, I learned that this isn't recommended, so it's just to answer my question directly:

Just a change on the final part of the code answers my question ( but again, it's not the recommended way to store files, as commented on the question.):

```
with ADOQuery, sql do
begin
  close;
  clear;
  add('INSERT INTO MyDatabase.dbo.MyFilesTable (EXTENSION,FILEBIN)');
  add('VALUES (:wextension, :wfilebin)');
  Parameters.ParamByName('wextension').Value := TPath.GetExtension(FName);
  Parameters.Items[1].LoadFromStream(Output,ftVarBytes); 
 ExecSQL;
end;
```

Just changing the way I was setting the parameter solved the problem. In this example, using the 'LoadFromStream' on the Paremeters.Items[n], where n is the parameter index, it worked very well. The ftVarBytes is the field type parameter.

Comment: Side note: It is recommended to avoid "with" statement. It's error prone.

Comment: @fpiette I didn't know about that, can you clarify why? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71419/why-should-i-not-use-with-in-delphi